# How can I use existing account on Google Play?

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I changed the phone and try to use my existing Google Play account. However when I open Google Play app it shows account creation form and when I enter my old Gamer ID it claims it's taken. However I cannot get to settings without logging in so my question is: is it possible to login somehow to existing account without creating a new one??

Comment: Go to Settings > Account and add your Google account. You should be able to use it in any Google services.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to hard reset the phone then try signing in again. Make sure you are at the page to log in to a existing account and not a new one. It should only ask that question if you are trying to make a new account using a email that is already in use.